# PHPUnit setup with Zend 1.12.3

Tags: macos, zend-framework, phpunit

I am just getting start with Zend Framework and seem to run into this problem

> Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no
>   testing actions will be created.

I am on mac 10.8.5, Using Zend Server 6 (free), and Zend Framework 1.12.3

Have pear and phpunit installed

> ```
> which pear
> /usr/local/zend/bin/pear
>
> which phpunit
> /usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit
> ```

from php info and include_path

> ```
> Loaded Configuration File     /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini 
>
> include_path=".:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/bin/pear:/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit:/usr/local/zend/share/pear:/usr/local/zend/share/pear/phpunit"
> ```

No matter what i put in the include_path, i always get the above notice, PHPUnit was not found in your include path.

I been searching and someone said zf.ini can cause this, and that file should be editted, however i can't seem to find such a file anywhere on my Mac. I do have previous Mamp and Xampp installations, but phpinfo() states the correct php.ini file loaded so i doubt that is the problem

Edit:

Okay so i finally managed to fix it. Using "zf.sh --setup" i found the paths to all the config files, including .zf.ini and how to edit it. The file did not exist, so i had to create it, and adding "include_path" to .zf.ini fixed the issue. However in the end i am overriding the php.ini which was probably being over ridden. I still like to know why adding pear path to php.ini didn't work, hopefully someone can explain that

Comment: Does the file `PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php` exist on your include_path? That's what ZF is actually checking to see whether it can find PHPUnit.

Comment: The file exists on "/usr/local/zend/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner". I tried adding this path and path with "/Version.php" at the end in my include_path, but no luck. And i am restarting zend server after every change.

Comment: `/usr/local/zend/share/pear` should be fine then. Something somewhere is overriding your include path, you need to work out what. I'd start by looking in your application.ini to see if there's anything include path related in there.

Comment: Note that you must not add the full path to the file you think is needed. PEAR works with relative paths inside `require_once` - it would for example `require_once "PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php";`, and this file can only be found if `/usr/local/zend/share/pear` is in the include path, not `/usr/local/zend/share/pear/PHPUnit` or `/usr/local/zend/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner` or `/usr/local/zend/share/pear/PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php`. The include path is a list of paths that gets added one after another to relative require paths if the file hasn't been found yet.

Comment: Also note that your `which pear` reveals the location of the pear executable file, not the location of the PEAR library. So it is useless to add the full path of that pear executable to the include path. The same applies to `which phpunit`.

Comment: @TimFountain don't see anything in application.ini about this, only includes the zend library and path to bootstrap.php, nothing else. Application.ini is generated with the new project, and the problem is phpunit not in the include path in php.ini, going to test if removing previous mamp and xampp does anything.

Comment: @Sven /usr/local/zend/share/pear is a part of the include_path in php.ini, and it also exists on that path too. I was just trying all sorts of combinations just to be sure, thanks for that input however